# Does anyone know what this menu bar app is?

Tags: applications, menu-bar

Does anyone know what this menu bar app is?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logo is the AirPlay logo, but I have seen it used by a number of programs. It's either the resolution settings for your outbound AirPlay (morriring), or I think (more likely) the window size of incoming AirDisplay connections through AirParrot or AirDisplay or similar AP server apps.

Answer (score 3):

It is the Airplay logo. If you press it you can for instance select your AppleTv as output. The box below in the screen shot with all the resolutions does not below to the logo marked red above.